# unexpected output when using next(generator)

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Here is the code:

```
from typing import Any, Generator, List, Set, Union
stream_type = Union[List[Any], str]

def valid_posts(stream: Generator[stream_type, None, None]) -> Set[int]:
    result = set()
    for post in stream():
        if post == "end_of_session":
            yield result
            result = set()       
            continue
        if post[2] == "hello":
            result.add(post[1])    
            

def stream():
    data = [
        [1, 1, "hello"],
        [1, 1, "world"],
        [1, 2, "hello"],
        [1, 2, "world"],
        [1, 3, "hello"],
        [1, 3, "world"],
        [1, 1, "hello"],
        [1, 1, "world"],
        "end_of_session",
        [2, 1, "hello"],
        [2, 1, "world"],
        [2, 2, "world"],
        [2, 2, "world"],
        [2, 3, "world"],
        [2, 3, "world"],
        "end_of_session",
    ]
    for item in data:
        yield item


# for post in valid_posts(stream):
#     print(post)
print(next(valid_posts(stream)))
print(next(valid_posts(stream)))
print(next(valid_posts(stream)))
print(next(valid_posts(stream)))
```

when I use the two lines that's commented out now (`for post in valid_posts(stream): print(post)`) it printed out expected result:

```
{1, 2, 3}
{1}
```

but when I use the four lines of `print(next(valid_posts(stream)))` it surprising print these:

```
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
```

my understanding we can use `next()` to call generator and it yields the result one by one till the end, but how come it just repeatedly print the first result in this case? Thanks

Comment: Copy-pasting this code into Pycharm highlights the `stream()` in `for post in stream():` in `valid_posts`, saying `'Generator' object is not callable`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `for post in valid_posts(stream):` you actually do:

```py
vp = valid_posts(stream) # save the iterator returned from valid_posts
print(next(vp))
print(next(vp))
print(next(vp))
print(next(vp))
# ... a until StopIteration is raised
```

In your usage, you call `valid_posts` over and over again instead of using the same iterator.

EDIT:
note that you also have severe type errors.
type annotations are only hints, and PyCharm screams to high heavens when I paste your code in.
The fact the annotations are there and the code runs, doesn't mean the code conforms to the annotations.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits, I got the "root cause" of your misunderstanding wrong the first times...